# Adding a class to li elements based on which url is the current location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have actually had it working once when I was assigning the selected class to an `<a>` tag, but, for my website id really like it to set the selected class on the whole `<li>`

Here is the html

```
<div class="left side-menu">
    <a href="index"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png"></a>
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li class="menu-button" id="home"><a href="index">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-button" id="about-us"><a href="about-us">About</a></li>
        <li class="menu-button" id="portfolio"><a href="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="menu-button" id="your-session"><a href="your-session">Your Session</a></li>
        <li class="menu-button" id="testimonials"><a href="testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li class="menu-button" id="contact-us"><a href="contact-us">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And Here is the Javascript.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        // store url for current page as global variable
    current_page = location.href.toLowerCase();
    alert(current_page);
    if (current_page.match()) {
        $("ul#navigation li#home").addClass('selected');
    } else if (current_page.match(/about-us/)) {
        $("ul#navigation li#about-us)").addClass('selected');
    } else if (current_page.match(/portfolio/)) {
        $("ul#navigation li#portfolio").addClass('selected');
    } else if (current_page.match(/your-session/)) {
        $("ul#navigation li#your-session").addClass('selected');
    } else if (current_page.match(/testimonials/)) {
        $("ul#navigation li#testimonials").addClass('selected');
    } else if (current_page.match(/contact-us/)) {
        $("ul#navigation li#contact-us").addClass('selected');
    } else { // don't mark any nav links as selected
        $("ul#navigation li").removeClass('selected');
    };
    });
</script>
```

The css is like

```
div.side-menu {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-image: url('/images/side-menu.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    min-height: 590px;
    position: relative;
    left: 37px;
    z-index: 9;
}
div.side-menu li{
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    /* HOVER OFF */
   -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
}
div.side-menu a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#c7ecf4;
}
div.side-menu li:hover a {
    color:#818E9E;
}
div.side-menu li:hover{
    background-color:#c7ecf4;
    /* HOVER ON */
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s; 
}
ul.navigation{
    padding-left: 18px;
}
ul.navigation li.selected {
    background-color: #c7ecf4;
}
```

I have looked at this a few times, each with a different approach. It seems that using an `<a>` tag is really simple, but trying to use an `<li>` instead is proving rather difficult.

Comment: Create [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Uhm I don't really get the problem. So you want to create a class "selected"? Just add .selected {} to your CSS. But you should really get into some basics first because this is not the way to approach this. First of all instead of use chain-ifs like that try switch case. And what exactly are you trying to achieve? You want to highlight a specific Menu entry according to the subsite you're on? Wouldn't do that with JavaScript, try native HTML/CSS or PHP if you want to use includes.

Comment: I have tried different approaches before. Ive had it working really neatly on my <a> tags. But on my <li> it had me stumped. So i found this code and fixed my mistake as outlined below and its almost all working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your  ul tag has a class named 'navigation'. Not an ID. But you assigned in jQuery code like that:

```
ul#navigation li
```

First, you must correct this. Change like that:

```
ul.navigation li
```

Now your code must be like that:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        // store url for current page as global variable
        current_page = location.href.toLowerCase();
        var pageNameParts = current_page.split('/');

        // You can look console to check pageNamePart contents
        // and then remove this for bracket
        for (var i = 0; i < pageNameParts.length; i++) {
            console.log(pageNameParts[i]);
        }

        if (pageNameParts.length == 3) { // It's not 1 because there is 'http://'
            $("ul.navigation li#home").addClass('selected');
        } else if (pageNameParts[4] == 'about-us') {
            $("ul.navigation li#about-us").addClass('selected');
        } else if (pageNameParts[4] == 'portfolio') {
            $("ul.navigation li#portfolio").addClass('selected');
        } else if (pageNameParts[4] == 'your-session') {
            $("ul.navigation li#your-session").addClass('selected');
        } else if (pageNameParts[4] == 'testimonials') {
            $("ul.navigation li#testimonials").addClass('selected');
        } else if (pageNameParts[4] == 'contact-us') {
            $("ul.navigation li#contact-us").addClass('selected');
        } else {
            $("ul.navigation li").removeClass('selected');
    };
    });
</script>
```

If it works for you, you can make code shorter like that:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        // store url for current page as global variable
        current_page = location.href.toLowerCase();
        var pageNameParts = current_page.split('/');

        // You can look console to check pageNamePart contents
        // and then remove this for bracket
        for (var i = 0; i < pageNameParts.length; i++) {
            console.log(pageNameParts[i]);
        }

        // First remove '.selected'
        $("ul.navigation li.selected").removeClass('selected')

        if (pageNameParts.length == 3) { // It's not 1 because there is 'http://'
            $("ul.navigation li#home").addClass('selected');
        } else {
            $("ul.navigation li#"+ pageNameParts[4]).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just the info i needed. It is 99% working now.. my only issue is that my home page is just the web address.. without having index or home afterwards. So when im on the homepage it doesnt show selected.

Obviously i have just quickly added a string into the current_page.match() for home because the way it is its just always matching on home because it was empty.

Comment: @jburley89 You can use split method. This method will give you a string array and you can check which page.
I edited my answer. If you look, you'll see this way.